# Generate Catalog Of Posts Based On Template

Tags: templates, list

Is there a way to print a hierarchy of posts/pages/custom post types based on page template?

EG. I am often asked to review another web site and I'd like a way to 'see' all the pages that are assigned to the 'Newsletter' PHP template and all the pages assigned to the 'Product Info' PHP template.

Is there a plug-in like that or some code one can recommend?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are off-topic per the [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all posts ordered by their template you need two functions: one for the query, and one to add a custom order.

#### Get the posts

```
function get_posts_by_template()
{
    add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'orderby_template' );

    $query = new WP_Query(
        array(
            //'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
            'post_type' => 'any',
            'orderby'  => 'title',
            'order'    => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => -1, // dangerous
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_wp_page_template',
                    'value' => '',
                    'compare' => '!='
                )
            )
        )
    );

    if ( empty ( $query->posts ) )
        return FALSE;

    return $query->posts;
}
```

#### Change the order

```
function orderby_template( $orderby )
{
    global $wpdb;

    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $orderby = $wpdb->postmeta . '.meta_value DESC, ' . $orderby;

    return $orderby;
}
```

For a nice overview we could use something like this:

```
function list_posts_by_template()
{
    $posts = get_posts_by_template();

    if ( ! $posts )
        return print 'no posts with a template found';

    static $template = '';

    foreach ( $posts as $post )
    {
        $post_template = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', TRUE ) . '<br>';

        if ( $post_template !== $template )
        {
            print "<h2>$post_template</h2>";
            $template = $post_template;
        }

        printf(
            '<p><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></p>',
            get_permalink( $post->ID ),
            esc_html( $post->post_title )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. I just didn't know where the template assignment was made in the db, but you took it to the next level. I think I'm going to make this an addition to my Admin UI right now. I'm surprised I haven't seen a plug-in like this before as I have a need for it =all= the time. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in what context you need this but *assigned* page templates are kept in `$wpdb->postmeta` under the `_wp_page_template` key so you can do something like ...

```
$templates = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template'");
var_dump($templates);
```

... to get your templates...

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'any',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => '_wp_page_template',
       'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    )
  )
);
$t = new WP_Query($args);
var_dump($t);
```

... to get posts to compare them against. They are associated by the `ID` == `post_id`

I suppose  you could combine the two somewhat with...

```
$templates = $wpdb->get_results(
  "SELECT post_id,meta_value,post_title 
  FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} 
  JOIN {$wpdb->posts} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id
  WHERE meta_key = '_wp_page_template'");
var_dump($templates);
```

You cannot get the [automagically assigned templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_Hierarchy_In_Detail) this way, if that is what you need.